# Reading web.configuration values in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application I want to read authorization section of web.config and modify that.
For that I am using the below code but I am not getting the values. So have a look at it and let me know if there is any way to read and update authorization section values
AuthorizationSection section;
my section is like the following

```
 <authorization>
       <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>
```

And this is the code:

```
configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
section = (AuthorizationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authorization"); 
SectionInformation sc= section.SectionInformation;
```

Thanks,
Hima.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
AuthorizationSection section = (AuthorizationSection)ConfigurationManager
                                   .GetSection("system.web/authorization");
```

Add reference to System.Configuration.dll

Update:

Try this:

```
    AuthorizationSection section = (AuthorizationSection)ConfigurationManager
                               .GetSection("system.web/authorization");
    foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in section.Rules)
    {
        //rule.Users <- StringCollection
        //rule.Action;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Raj.. I tried with that but its not reading the internal section that  is <deny users="?"/> 
I am not getting that value